# How to get AccessToken with Spring Boot for Azure B2C

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

to make it very clear again, access is via Azure **B2C**. This is obviously a big difference, because there are two different ways to access it.

I followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-oidc

I have tried the other guide before but this does not work for **B2C**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-active-directory

The authentication works fine. I get redirected to the login page and directed back after sucessful login. User Infos can be requested from the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`.

In the Browser my application has a JSESSIONID.

On the same domain there is a REST Service I want to consume directly from the App Frontend with Vue.js.

So I thought I'd deliver an AccessToken to the frontend that it can use to access the REST API.

I searched and found a relatively simple example: https://spring.io/blog/2018/03/06/using-spring-security-5-to-integrate-with-oauth-2-secured-services-such-as-facebook-and-github

But when I trie to inject the `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService`:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user")
public ResponseEntity<User> test(@NonNull final OAuth2AuthenticationToken token,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal(expression = "idToken") final OidcIdToken idToken, final
OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService) {
    LOG.debug("GET called on /api/user resource");
    LOG.debug("OidcIdToken: {}", idToken.getTokenValue());

    final OAuth2AuthorizedClient client = clientService
            .loadAuthorizedClient(token.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(), token.getName());

    LOG.debug("Access: {}", client.getAccessToken().getTokenValue());
```

the following error occures on access:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_231]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.createAttribute(ModelAttributeMethodProcessor.java:216) ~[spring-web-5.2.3.RELEASE.jar:5.2.3.RELEASE]
```

Can someone please push me in the right direction?

**Update**

It was my fault. From the guide i got the impression `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` can be injected via the method.
That was not the case. It only works if that class is injected via constructor or direct `@inject`.

Now I have my access token...

Comment: If your issue has been resolved, you can add an answer.

Comment: @Nabor can you provide a sample code if possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OAuth2AuthorizedClientService must be injected into the class, not as method parameter. See above...